# How to forbid HTTP access to PHP files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs using `mod_rewrite`. This is the rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1\.php
```

If the user inputs `example.com/contact`, the contents of the `example.com/contact.php` file will load.

The problem is, this leaves me with duplicate content because now both `example.com/contact` and `example.com/contact.php` display the same information.

I'd like to forbid access to all PHP files if users attempt to access via HTTP but allow script access (I need my application to work). How can I do this using .htaccess?

Everything I've tried blocks both script and HTTP access. For example, using the following in .htaccess forbids HTTP access but also causes my script to stop working:

```
Deny from all
```

Comment: you' d better choose an other alias. Otherwise you 'd have conflicts all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `THE_REQUEST` for that.

Your code should look like this now

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# if file exists and has ".php" extension then redirect to extensionless equivalent
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]+)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# if uri + ".php" exists then internally rewrite to "uri.php"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

- `http://example.com/contact.php` will redirect to `http://example.com/contact`
- `http://example.com/contact` will internally rewrite to `/contact.php`

Comment: Works amazingly. You don't have to because I'm going to upvote and accept regardless, but any chance of explaining what's going on?

Comment: Using `THE_REQUEST` allows you to avoid matching internal rewrites from the server (that's why you had a loop). I've also added a line describing each rule

Comment: Thanks for explaining, all makes perfect sense. This is such a great solution! One thing I noticed was my `example.com/index.php` file was redirecting to `example.com/index`. This is probably only useful to my own set up but to ensure both `index.php` and `index` redirect to `example.com` I added the following after your last rewrite rule: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]` - Thanks again!